# Regex to parse a MySQL query for JOIN's

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I am using regex to parse a MySQL query for JOIN's, currently using this:

```
if (preg_match_all('/\s(LEFT|INNER|OUTER|RIGHT)?\sJOIN\s(.*)/i', $sql, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches); exit;
}
```

This doesn't quite work as I want an array of strings like this:

```
[0] => formats ON articles.article_format_id = formats.format_id
[1] => article_categories ON articles.article_id = article_categories.article_id
```

My current regex returns this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  INNER JOIN formats ON articles.article_format_id = formats.format_id INNER JOIN article_categories ON articles.article_id = article_categories.article_id 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => INNER
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => formats ON articles.article_format_id = formats.format_id INNER JOIN article_categories ON articles.article_id = article_categories.article_id 
        )

)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What about: `UPDATE foo SET bar='join me in my regex quest!'`? :)

Comment: true, how can I improve the regex?

Comment: @Bart Kiers: Missing white spaces: `UPDATE foo SET bar=' join me! '`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The greedy .* might take everything to the end. So change the regex to:

```
/(?:LEFT|INNER|OUTER|RIGHT)?\sJOIN\s((?:(?!(?:LEFT|INNER|OUTER|RIGHT)?\sJOIN).)+)/i
```

See here: [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/I0dr9xywme)

And you might have to use `preg_match_all` to find all matches.

Comment: thanks, almost works! take a look at http://pastebin.com/pfdNTzvS if you run that code the last element in the $matches array [2] is what I am looking for however it leaves 'INNER' on the end of the first string! can this be improved upon at all?

Comment: Ok, I change it, so it does omit the INNER and other prefixes.